# "Failed to export application" in Eclipse 4.4.1 for Android with ADT 23.0.4

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I want to export my Android app from Eclipse, the export process starts normally but after a few seconds (when the whole process should actually take a minute) it fails. The following error message appears:

> Failed to export application

That's all Eclipse is telling me. I'm using Ecliipse 4.4.1 with the Android Development Toolkit 23.0.4.1468518.

When I then right-click the app, choose "Android Tools" and then "Export Unsigned Application Package", it fails again, but with more verbose error messages:

[image]

As you can see, it says:

> 'Android Release Export' has encountered a problem.
>
> Failed to export application

And strangely, it lists a file `bin/$1$1.class` which apparently cannot be found. There's no obvious reason why this file shouldn't be found, however.

Only when I delete folders `bin` and `gen` and then clear the project, it works. But only once -- and after every successful run on the device or export to an APK, I have to repeat the step described before.

Any ideas why this happens? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had multiple issues with Export Application Package in Eclipse before. Sometimes switching *Project - Build Automatically* off helped, something deleting `bin` folder and cleaning project helped. But the best and always working solution I found was a migration to `Ant` build.

If you are interested, here is how it works. It was [surprisingly simple](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html). Navigate into project's folder and execute

```
android update project -p .
```

It will created a *build.xml* file. Repeat same for all used library projects, if any. And you are done. Now calling `ant release` will create released apk-file. If you want app to be signed, add `key.store`, `key.alias`, `key.store.password` and `key.alias.password` to *local.properties* file inside your project. Now you can build new apk with a single command. Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading ADT.

Also, check your res folder. Sometimes duplication of folder may cause this error. For example, suppose u have two sub directories with same name in assets folder, this error may occur. Check your application folder thoroughly in the explorer

Answer (score 1):

1. Refresh the project (project right-click > refresh)
2. Clean the project (Window 'Project' Menu > Clean...)
3. Fix Android Project (project right-click > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties)erties.

ADT is not perfect and sometimes it gets random errors that are fixed with a general clean-up.

Comment: @user2455320 there's nothing on my proguard code, never cared to change it, really

Answer (score 1):

First clean your project then deselect "Build Automatically" option from Project/Build Automatically. 
Now try to export it.

Answer (score 1):

first delete .meta folder from workspace ,restart eclipse import application and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I had imported a project that was originally built on a Windows computer onto my Mac.   I eventually noticed that my .project file had references to a "C:\" drive that did not exist in my current environment.   For me the references were a result of "linked folders" that used absolute paths instead of project or workspace variables.   Once I fixed those, the export process worked.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your work space, just copy the project file and transfer it to the computer you want to be in, then use import tool to import it.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to change the computer. It's just that exporting doesn't work correctly.